# How to set Bottom Sheet position to top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to create a expandable container that have multiple controls like textentry and buttons.

So I have implemented a bottom sheet but I want to set this position on top.

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Show Buttom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context){
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: controller.stream,
                  builder:(context,snapshot) => GestureDetector(
                      onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details)
{
                        position = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height- 
                      details.globalPosition.dy;
                        print('position dy = ${position}');

                        position.isNegative?Navigator.pop(context)

                            :controller.add(position);

                      },
                      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                      child:
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data:200.0,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Text('Child'),
                      )),
                );

              });

            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: A Simple Top Modal Sheet for Flutter: https://morioh.com/p/0f80b5c68d71

Answer (score 22):

Looking at the [Material Design reference for Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom) it does suggest that the usage be ergonomic, meaning it should be at the bottom because it's easier to reach with your thumb (when using a phone). There don't seem to be other examples of "Top Sheets", implying there are better ways of handling a click of a button that's located at the top of the screen. For example in Gmail, clicking your avatar produces a Card that's positioned a little below the button.

Having said that, here is one way to create a "Top Sheet":

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.star),
  onPressed: () {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).dialogLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      pageBuilder: (context, _, __) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Card(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item 1'),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('item1'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item 2'),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('item2'),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Item 3'),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('item3'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      transitionBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.easeOut,
          ).drive(Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(0, -1.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          )),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you know any way to make this Dismissible & Draggable ? (Dragging bottom to top to hide)

Answer (score 1):

I think the widget you want is a BackDrop.

[Example here](https://medium.com/@CORDEA/implement-backdrop-with-flutter-73b4c61b1357)

And from the [Actual Flutter Gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/backdrop.dart) they also use it in the options

Comment: Actually I have a button on app bar name is filter, After click on filter button a overlay half screen open which have multiple Entry Text and button and after button click the overlay screen will dismiss. this overlay screen will come from top and back to top after dismiss like slide.

Answer (score 1):

After remove return of Icon Button it will work.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.star),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showGeneralDialog(
                      context: context,
                      barrierDismissible: true,
                      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      barrierLabel:
                          MaterialLocalizations.of(context).dialogLabel,
                      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      pageBuilder: (context, _, __) {
                        return Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Card(
                                child: ListView(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('Item 1'),
                                      onTap: () =>
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop('item1'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('Item 2'),
                                      onTap: () =>
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop('item2'),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text('Item 3'),
                                      onTap: () =>
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop('item3'),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                      transitionBuilder:
                          (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                        return SlideTransition(
                          position: CurvedAnimation(
                            parent: animation,
                            curve: Curves.easeOut,
                          ).drive(Tween<Offset>(
                            begin: Offset(0, -1.0),
                            end: Offset.zero,
                          )),
                          child: child,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```