# how to show ModelBottomSheet from top

Tags: flutter, search, widget, flutter-widget, searchfiltercollection

guys! ModelBottomSheet shows from bottom. Is there any way to show it from top. or is there another alternate widget for that function.
Actually I want to add a filter with a search bar. When I click on it something like ModelSheet should open from top. Please guide me
[I've added picture of what I want to build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeP9v.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Bottom Sheet position to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56440920/how-to-set-bottom-sheet-position-to-top)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel), slideDirection: SlideDirection.DOWN

[PanelController](https://pub.dev/documentation/sliding_up_panel/latest/sliding_up_panel/PanelController-class.html)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      slideDirection: SlideDirection.DOWN,
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: That's nearly the thing. But What my client requires is that the SlidingPanel should Open when I click on search filter icon button.
Thanks for by the way bro

Comment: you can always use PanelController to .show() or .open() by button

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
            actions: [
              PopupMenuButton(
                  itemBuilder: (context) => [
                        PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Container(
                                  child: Column ( children: [......]
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).